# How to parse number from middle of string

Tags: javascript, actionscript-3, apache-flex, flex3

I need to parse some numbers from a string, I can get the last number easily but wonder how to get the number mid string reliably. In this case the number 12?

```
var mystring = 'group 999999999 group-session-info 12 of 50';
var i;
var num; //how to get num "12"
var numOf;
i= mystring.lastIndexOf(" ");
if (i != -1) {
   numOf= mystring.substr(i);
}
alert(numOf); // = 50
```

Thanks

Comment: Are numbers and words always separated by a space?

Comment: @PM 77-1 yes seems so

Comment: is the question for javascript or actionscript? please remove the relevant tags since both language are not the same at all. All posted answers are javascript is that what you need?

Comment: @BotMaster my implementation will be Actionscript. I added Javascript tag due to the similarities in the languages and basically to draw quick attention to my question. I can easily type the variables etc myself.

Do you have a pure actionscript solution?

Comment: I figured, that's a bit unfair of you since many of the javascript solution given are not applicable to AS3. Those are different language and even the answer you accepted as is is not compatible with as3. I thought there was rules against that practice?

Comment: all vote downs are removed since the javascript tag was imo misused here on purpose. I will post the correct AS3 answer as reference.

Comment: @BotMaster indeed, javascript tags get immediate attention whereas actionscript take a bit longer as it seems to be dying out. I wanted a quick answer and neglected to think of the future users who may be confused by the javascript responses. If it is my question and i am happy to receive javascript and/or actionscript responses isn't that ok?

Comment: I guess but maybe you should clarify everything right at the start.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If the items are always in the format supplied. I would split using the space character.

```
var mystring = 'group 999999999 group-session-info 12 of 50';
var num = parseInt(mystring.split(' ')[3]); // 4th item which is 12
```

Comment: voted down. That's only one part of a solution, where's the rest? + untyped variable.

Comment: @BotMaster - The answer is valid based on the question asked. Vince-Lowe is aware he is dealing with a string and wants to extract '12' from the provided string. What he does after extracting it is up to him. If he wants in as an integer he I've updated my answer to show him how. However, I disagree with your comment of my answer being incomplete.

Comment: this implementation works fine in actionscript as well as javascript, remembering to type the variable in actionscript as BotMaster points out. 
`var num:int = parseInt(mystring.split(' ')[3]);`

Answer (score 8):

Try using regular expression to extract all numbers from the string

```
var mystring = 'group 999999999 group-session-info 12 of 50';
var r = /\d+/g;
mystring.match(r)
```

The last sentence will result in an array:
    [ '999999999', '12', '50' ]

But currently each element in the array is a string. Using parseInt() can turn them into numbers.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 4):

You'll need to know the context, or know how many numbers there are to find.

With context (for instance, `12` has `of` after it):

```
var match = mystring.match(/(\d+) of/);
var num = match && match[1];
```

`num` will be the string `"12"` or `null` if no number followed by "of" was found.

With knowing how many there are, you just grab all the numbers in the string:

```
var nums = mystring.match(/\d+/g);
```

Now `nums` is an array with the strings `"999999999"`, `"12"`, and `"99"` in it. (Thanks to epascarello for reminding me that `match` returns an array with [his excellent answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33762829/157247).)

Comment: untyped variable, voted down like the others. Is it a trend here on SO to always show answer with untyped variable which escape compiler checking? Systematically this sets up PO for failure down the road.

Comment: @BotMaster: Note *"`num` will be **the string `"12"`**"* and *"`nums` is an array with **the strings `"999999999"`, `"12"`, and `"99"`**..."* I left it to the OP to use their favorite way of converting from string to number (more accurately, the way most suited to their task). I did *not* "set them up".

Comment: @BotMaster: Further, if you're going to nit-pick, at least try to get your terminology right: **All** variables in JavaScript are untyped. The above would be whether I did `num = +num` or not. What you meant was "Results in a string, not a number." :-)

Comment: If you're talking about Action Script, well, the question is tagged `javascript`, too, no great surprise if the OP gets JavaScript answers.

Comment: once PO remove all AS3 tags (as he should) I will remove all my vote downs since none of the answer can apply to AS3.

Answer (score 1):

Simple with a regular expression and use map to convert the array of strings to numbers.

```
var mystring = 'group 999999999 group-session-info 12 of 50';
var nums = mystring.match(/\d+/g).map(Number);
```

Comment: @BotMaster What are you talking about? Are you talking about `Number`? Do you know what that actually is doing? Please explain your downvote, trying to figure out where the "untyped" variable is since JavaScript seems to lack them.

Comment: His issue is the ActionScript tag and using var instead of a typed variable. Apparently would rather snipe from the sidelines than do something constructive, like answering the question, or *politely* pointing out how he would declare the variable.

Answer (score 0):

Just to show the correct way but in correct AS3 code and not Javascript for reference:

```
var mystring:String = 'group 999999999 group-session-info 12 of 50';
var reg:RegExp =  /\d+/g;
var numbers:Array = mystring.match(reg);
trace(Number(numbers[0]))
trace(Number(numbers[1]))
trace(Number(numbers[2]))
```